# Sort arbitrary values given from command line

Tags: python, sorting, floating-point, int

I need to be able to accept arbitrary values (ints, floats) in any order in the command line and then sort and print them. I can do it easily with just ints or just floats but I'm stuck on trying to read both. I have the args reading showing as `Namespace(floats=[6.5], integers=[5, 10, 8, 4])`. I need all these numbers put into a single list and then printed as sorted. Recommendations on how to approach this?

A problem I'm running into is that the arguments have to be in a certain order, the ints have to be first and then the floats, but I need to be able to input them in any order.

As an example.

```
$ sortNum.py 5 9.9 14 1.1
1.1, 5, 9.9, 14
```

My code below:

```
try:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sort some arbitrary numbers by ascending or descending order')
    parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+', help='numbers for the sorter')
    parser.add_argument('floats', metavar='F', type=float, nargs='+', help='floats for the sorter')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # print the sorted values of user input from cmd line
    print(sorted(args.integers + args.floats))

    # print all the sys argument passed from cmd line including the program name
    print(sys.argv)

except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
```

I'm getting this error:
sortNum.py: error: argument N: invalid int value: '1.1'
when I try to enter 1.1 as my second argument. I'm using the following arguments to test: 5 1.1 10 8 4 6.5
The number values themselves don't really matter, just that they can be any float or int and need to be sorted.

Comment: `sorted(args.floats + args.integers)`? Given that you don't *actually show your code*, it's hard to make more useful suggestions.

Comment: OK, thanks! This is my first python program (outside of hello world). I appreciate the help!

Comment: Don't put answers (or *"answered"*) in the question, and give a [mcve] in the future. Also, note: http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/

Comment: Ok, issue still exists. I can't put the numbers in any order. In this case, the numbers have to be ints and floats, but it needs to be able to accept them in any order.

Comment: Then [edit] the question, noting [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you can access the arguments thanks to sys. Just do:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

and it should show all the arguments in the right order, the fact is that you will have the file name in the argv list which is bad !

So you can remove it thanks to

```
numbers = sys.argv[1:]
```

Which will to a copy without the first element.

Then you can sort the elements thanks to this code :

```
print sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: float(x))
```

What it does is to sort the elements, but instead of considering the element themself it will to the sort on their float casted value.

Your script can then be written like this :

```
import sys

print sys.argv
numbers = sys.argv[1:]
print sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: float(x))
```

Here we are I hope it helped you !

Comment: That is very helpful, my only issue is that when I try to add a float and then another int, it says invalid value. Do I need to make a change to my parser arguments?

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to accept values as some kind of generic Object and then cast them but I'm thinking that might be overboard.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it based on your answer. I just needed to remove the argument parsers. They were throwing it off. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry I missed the edit you did. 

I took a look, and I think you can't really do what you want with argparse, because either you will have to define an exact amount of number you are waiting for or it will not work. 

What is happening is that without "--" in the name of the argument. Argparse consider it as positional. To overcome this problem you added nargs=+ and it is not a bad idea ! 

The problem is that argparse ends with two undefined sized positional arguments with different type.

Comment: So the solution is either to add positional ("just rename integer by --intergers and floats by --floats") arguments but in this case you can't mix floats and integers. Or you can just remove all the argparse and do the mix after yourself like you suggested ! :)

Comment: Sorry ! Just saw you solved it ! Good job ! Have a good day !